# nuevo registro en una tabla usando formularios LibreOffice-Base

Tags: macros, basic

llevo un tiempo aprendiendo Basic en Libreoffice Base. Estoy construyendo una pequeña base de datos sobre la cual quiero, usando una macro, que el usuario final pueda adicionar registros por medio de un formulario.

El formulario es bastante sencillo, tiene dos campos de texto (llamémoslos tField1 y tField2) y un botón (boton1). Para ilustrar, la tabla tiene dos campos además del ID (variable1, variable2).

Lo que busco es que al oprimir boton1 el texto en tField1 se agregue a variable1 creando un nuevo registro y lo de tField2 se agregue a variable2, completando el registro.

El primer inconveniente que encontré, es obtener el valor de los campos. De momento he intentado lo siguiente:

```
Sub boton1(oEvent as Object)
dim oForm as Object 
dim oField as Object
dim oTField as Object

oTField=oEvent.Source.Model
oForm=oTField.Parent 
oField=oForm.getByName("tField1")
'...        
End Sub
```

El problema con ese código es que obtengo un elemento de tipo Object y no un String para ingresar en la tabla.

El Segundo inconveniente es que no sé de qué manera agregar dicho String a la tabla mencionada.

Espero haber descrito el problema con claridad y de antemano agradezco la ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con una de estas propiedades.

```
oForm.getByName("tField1").value
oForm.getByName("tField1").Text
oForm.getByName("tField1").string
oForm.getByName("tField1").getstring
```

> El Segundo inconveniente es que no sé de qué manera agregar dicho String a la tabla mencionada.

Para insertar los datos debes ejecutar un consulta, algo así:

```
oStat=ThisDatabaseDocument.CurrentController.ActiveConnection.CreateStatement
sSQL="INSERT INTO ""MiTabla"" (""NombreCampo1"",""NombreCampo2"",""NombreCampo3"")VALUES("& Variable1 & "," & Variable2 & "," & Variable3 &")"
Stat.ExecuteUpdate(sSQL)
```